# update query not working in php and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

i'm trying to create a multiple photo uploading script in php. All seems to be working fine except the update query. tried updating it manually in phpmyadmin and the problem of not updating persists don't know what to do can any experts help me solve this problem.

here is the update query:

```
 try {
          $sql1="update photos 
          set 
          filename='{$db_file_name}',
          upload_date=now() where user='{$_SESSION['id']}' ";
          $st1=$conn->prepare($sql1);
          $st1->execute();

     } 
  catch (Exception $exc) {
          echo $exc->getMessage();   
     }
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Having clean code, nicely indented, is the first step towards bug free code. Just a bit of dicipline will go a long way. I mean, if even your question contains messy code, what about your real code?

Comment: `user` is a keyword, better use backticks around it. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: @JayBlanchard the file name is random numbers with date generated by php and session id is already created. I don't see injection attacks in it

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i tried the back ticks still it is not working.

Comment: 'not working' is never a good description of a problem. Try to be more specific. echo you query, and try it in phpMyAdmin. You have to realize there's no way for me to check your code. Any of the variables present could be invalid, who knows?

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is a keyword, better use backticks around it. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

```
 try {
     $sql = "UPDATE `photos` 
             SET `filename` = :filename, 
                 `upload_date` = NOW() 
             WHERE `user` = :sess_id";
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindValue(":sess_id", $_SESSION['id']);
     $stmt->bindValue(":filename", $db_file_name);
     $stmt->execute();
} catch (....) {
   ....
}
```

Perhaps better still, don't use keywords as column names, try `userId`.

Comment: Good advice, but only reserved words require backticks.

Comment: @miken32  I did them all so you don't have to check if something might be a reserved word. It can't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would verify again whether all the variables you are using are correct (photos, filename, etc.). i.e. compare them letter by letter with your table. If that looks alright, a little more information wouldn't be bad. Are you getting any errors? If so, what are they saying? What else have you tried so far?

Moreover, I would suggest making your code a little easier to read like so:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($st1 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `photos` SET `filename` = ?, `upload_date` = ? WHERE `user` = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters (ssi = string, string, integer)*/
    $st1->bind_param("ssi", $db_file_name, now(), $_SESSION['id']);

    /* execute query */
    $st1->execute();

    /* close statement */
    $st1->close();
}
```